# ionic check jwt token expiration on every request

Tags: ionic3, jwt

I want to check whether the jwt token has expired or not on every api request.

The suggestion given on the below question is not feasible:

[Ionic 2 retrying API call with new access token if unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45291910/ionic-2-retrying-api-call-with-new-access-token-if-unauthorized?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Is there a way wherein I can incorporate this check with some standard code without checking for the function **tokenNotExpired(null,token)** every time?

I'm using .net core WEB API.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting your JWT?  I know systems like Auth0 will send an `expires_in` element back with your access token.  That seems like the most convenient thing to hold on to to tell you when the JWT will expire.

Comment: since jwt does not support storage of ionic I'm as usual saving it in localStorage.

Comment: That's where you're storing it.  Where does it originate from though?  What is your auth provider which generates the token?  Hopefully they give you an expiration date when you first obtain the token.

Comment: Im using jwt token

Comment: Who/what creates your jwt?

Comment: Im using jwt services in my api to generate it, in short it is coming from my api and is being assigned to localstorage

Comment: OK.  When your API generates the JWT initially, maybe you can send an expiration date with it to your app.  Then your app can keep track of when the JWT will expire from that point forward.